# MySQL/PHP: Using multiple sub-queries in a query selecing multiple results, is it a bad idea?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, forum, subquery

Sorry if the title is a little... Crappy. Basically I'm writing a small forum and using multiple sub-queries to select the number of threads, number of posts, and the date of the last post in a forum while grabbing the forum's information at the same time to display on the main page!

This is my query, since I suck at explaining things:

```
SELECT `f`.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(`id`)
    FROM `forum_threads` 
    WHERE `forumId1` = `f`.`id1`
        AND `forumId2` = `f`.`id2`) AS `threadCount`,
    (SELECT COUNT(`id`)
    FROM `forum_posts` 
    WHERE `forumId1` = `f`.`id1`
        AND `forumId2` = `f`.`id2`) AS `postCount`,
    (SELECT `date`
    FROM `forum_posts` 
    WHERE `forumId1` = `f`.`id1` 
        AND `forumId2` = `f`.`id2` 
        ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1) AS `lastPostDate`
FROM `forum_forums` AS `f`
ORDER BY `f`.`position` ASC, `f`.`id1` ASC;
```

And am using the general foreach loop to display the results:

```
foreach($forums AS $forum) {
    echo $forum->name .'<br />';
    echo $forum->threadCount .'<br />';
    echo $forum->postCount .'<br />';
    echo $forum->lastPostDate .'<br />';
}
```

(Not exactly like that of course, but for the sake of explaining...)

Now I was wondering if that would be "bad" for performance, or if there was any better way of doing it? Assuming there are quite a few posts and threads in each forum.

I was originally storing "posts", "threads", and "lastPost" columns in the forum table itself, and was going to increment (posts = posts + 1) the values every time someone created a new thread or post. Though I had this idea as well and was wondering if it was any good. :P

Comment: Make sure you have defined your table indexes properly otherwise it's going to be a bit heavy on the server. Alternatively you could cache those values as individual fields in forum_forums and update the value when a new thread or post is created

Comment: Sorry, just realised you already thought of that last option

Comment: I was doing that at first, though couldn't it cause problems if two people submit a post or thread at the same time?

Comment: Use transactions if you're concerned about that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do things a bit differently: 
It seems to me that all these three fields: `threadCount`, `postCount` and `lastPostDate` are fields that you can maintain on a separate table, say `forum_stats` which will hold only 4 columns:
* forum_id
* thread_count
* post_count
* last_post_date

These columns can be updated via. [*trigger*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) upon insert/update.
If you'll pay this small overhead during the update operations - you'll get a very fast query for the `select` (and it will remain very fast regardless the number of forums/posts/threads you have).

**Another approach (not us good TMO):**
Create the stats table and run a daily (or every few hours) a [*batch-job*](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) which will update the stats. The price is that the data you display will never be up-to-date, and the job might require resources, you might want to run the job only at night, for example, since it's heavy and you don't want it to effect the majority of your website visitors.

Comment: I'd also view this as the best option. Although store in the forum table directly (as the OP was considering), no need for a separate table. You'll probably need the batch job for corrections as well.

Comment: @Robbie I suggested to store it on a separate table on purpose, in order to avoid locking-problems when such a batch-job runs. Another advantage of separating the tables is the option to index more columns (the "cost" is less expensive). Further, I have no idea how many columns the `forum` table already holds, when a table gets too big - it effects performance as well. That said, assuming that the table is not too big and we choose the first option, then you're probably right and another table might be redundant.

Comment: The forum_forums table itself only has 10 columns, not including the "posts", "threads", and "lastPost" columns. Assuming I'm using transactions there wouldn't be much of a problem would there? Correct me if I'm wrong, never used transactions to be honest.

Comment: @AlexRains I believe that transactions will have effect like any update (from locking perspective), but I might be wrong and it could be worse. As for `VIEW` - I wouldn't recommend using it since the `VIEW` is calculated every time it's being called - so I don't see any advantage of using a `VIEW` over your original solution (a simple `SELECT`).

Comment: Well I mean like when someone goes to post a thread and then the "forum_forums" row will need to be updated to add a new post, thread, and lastPostDate. Ie "UPDATE forum_forums SET posts = posts + 1, threads = threads + 1, lastPostDate = NOW() WHERE..." etc. That's the real reason I was thinking up the whole nested query thing, as I didn't want those UPDATE queries conflicting with each other if many users were posting at the same time. And I've never used transactions. :P

Comment: As for the whole batch-job thing, users may complain or report it as a bug if they see that the date of the last post on the forum index page doesn't match up with the one on the view threads page. :( To be honest I'd like it to be fully updated all the time.

Comment: @AlexRains if you update the same record you don't need `transactions`. `transactions` are made to group a batch of updates into a one "call" which is done altogether - or none at all.

Comment: That's what I thought when I read over it. Though it seems like updating the forum_forums row like that (posts = posts + 1) would have conflicting issues if tons of people were all doing it at the same time? Maybe I'm just overly paranoid.

Comment: @AlexRains today databases can deal with hundreds of calls per second, so I don't believe it should be an issue.

Comment: Fair enough then. Though for the sake of being thorough, and annoyingly paranoid, would there be any good way around that?

Comment: sure, like @tadman suggested, you can run a batch-job that will go over the records, once in a while, and re-validate the sums. but it would be an over-kill TMO.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this kind of thing is terrible from a performance perspective and you'd be better off with counter columns that you can fetch from a single row. Keeping these in sync can be annoying, but there's no retrieval cost once they're in there.

You've identified the data you're retrieving, so what you need to do next is figure out how to put that data in there in the first place. @alfasin's answer describes an example schema, and while putting it in a separate table is one idea, there's usually not too much in the way of trouble just putting them in the main one. If you're worried about locking, update in smaller batches.

One approach is to write a `TRIGGER` that updates the counters as records are added and removed from the various tables. This tends to hide a lot of the complexity which can be a bad thing if the logic changes often and people need to be aware of how the system works.

A simple method is to just fiddle with the columns using an additional query after you've created or removed something that would have updated them. For instance, adjusting the last-posted-date is trivial if you do it at the time a post is created.

If these counters get a bit screwy, and they will eventually, you need a method to bring them back into sync. An easy way is to write a `VIEW` that produces the same results your query does now, perhaps re-written to use `LEFT JOIN` instead, and then `UPDATE` against that if that's possible. This may involve using a temporary table if MySQL can't cope with updating a table with a view of itself, but that's usually not a big deal.

Comment: Thanks! I was really thinking it would hurt performance, but wasn't really sure on the reliability of transactions and all that to maintain the actual post count and not miss a post or two somewhere along the line.